# Accessing File present in GCS using Java 'File' class

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to access a File present in Google Cloud Storage ("gs://balajee/abc.txt") using Java 'File' class?

```
File file=new File("C:/Users/balajeev/Desktop/abc.txt");
```

This is how we access the files present in local windows folders. What would be its equivalence in accessing the files present in GCS? I can have many Java APIs talking to cloud storage and allowing me to access my file, but this a specific requirement where I need to have 'object' of 'File' class for further processing and the text file is present in GCS.

Any leads?

Answer (score 1):

You want the NIO Provider for Google Cloud Storage. It's here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-contrib/google-cloud-nio

Once you've got it set up, you can use it like so:

```
Path path = Paths.get(URI.create("gs://bucket/lolcat.csv"));
try (InputStream input = Files.openInputStream(path)) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I believe this would solve my purpose if not stuck by this exception : java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider: Provider com.google.cloud.storage.contrib.nio.CloudStorageFileSystemProvider could not be instantiated

Comment: Any idea why this is happening? @Brandon

Comment: Nope. Is there more to the error? Maybe post it as another question.

Comment: Balajee it may help to add the dependency and set things up as described at https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/v0.30.0/google-cloud-contrib/google-cloud-nio